# Deriving a distribution function in a weird set-up

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Z$, where $Pr(X = 0) = Pr(X =
2) = 1/2$ and where $Z$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 2]$. Let $Y$ be defined such that
$Pr(Y = X)= 1 - Pr(Y = Z) = 1/2$

How can one start deriving the distribution function of $Y$?

For example, I understand how to do it for 1 variable. Say, let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\alpha$ then $Pr(X \leq x)= 1-\exp(-\alpha  x)$

Let $Y= \alpha \exp(X)$ where $\alpha >0$. Similarly, I will try to find the corresponding cdf.

Firstly, $Y$ takes values in $(\lambda,  \infty)$ since $\exp(X)$ takes values in $(1, \infty)$

Then, $Pr(Y \leq y) = Pr(\alpha \exp(X) \le y)$ for all $y \ge \lambda$

By simple transformations one arrives that the cdf is equal to $1-(\lambda/y)^\alpha$

Clearly, it is a pareto random variable.

How do I extend this logic to the case of the interaction of two variables mentioned previously?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you! I will read the guidelines and edit it accordingly.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos many thanks for the relevant tutorials! Just managed to change the structure.

Comment: The conditions  $\ Pr(Y=X)=1−Pr(Y=Z)=\frac{1}{2}\ $ are insufficient to determine the distribution of $\ Y\ $. If$$Y=\cases{X&if $\ X=0$\\Z&if $\ X=2\ $,}$$ for instance, then $\ Y\ $ satisfies the conditions, and  $\ Pr(Y=0)=\frac{1}{2}\ $, $\ Pr(Y=2)=0\ $. But if$$Y=\cases{X&if $\ X=2$\\Z&if $\ X=0\ $,}$$ then $\ Y\ $ still satisfies the conditions, but $ \ Pr(Y=0)=0\ $ and$\ Pr(Y=2)=\frac{1}{2}\ $.